# Crashes when trying to sign in

Tags: visual-studio-2013

Came to work this monday and started up Visual Studio 2013 and it says my license has expired and I need to sign in to extend it, but when I press the sign in button VS crashes and says "Microsoft Visual Studio 2013 has stopped working".

I've tried repairing my installation of VS but I get the same error.

I've tried running VS in safe mode but I get the same error.

I've tried debugging VS and found this message "An unhandled exception of type 'System.ExecutionEngineException' occurred in Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.WebApi.dll" but I find nothing relevant when googling it.

Any suggestions are on how to fix this are welcome. I've had this version installed since it came out and I have a license for it. And I've signed in before without problems.

Comment: Solved it! I installed update 3 for VS and now it dosen't crash anymore.

Comment: I have VS 2013 Update 3, and I'm still having this issue. I've also tried repairing it, to no avail.

Comment: @martin_costello yeah my problem came back after a while, but then I installing a CTP of VS 2014, and after that VS 2013 started working again.